# Connect attempt from '192.168.xxx.xxx' unable to authenticate?

Tags: asterisk, pbx, asteriskami

I'm trying to implement an AMI service, actually it works pretty good, I can add members, remove members etc etc, but every 1-5 minutes I get an exception. Looking in the asterisk manager I find this error. Does anybody knows how to solve this issue.

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague, as we don't have enough information.

At my best guess, i think your AMI client code gets a TCP disconnect and automatically reconnects, but does not correctly "logs in" to the asterisk manager interface after the reconnect.

You can debug this by capturing the communication between your AMI client and asterisk via TCPDUMP and look at the trace at the time of the failure. You should see a second TCP session opening, missing the login event if my guess is right.

Comment: Thanks, you were right, I did what you suggested and I found the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should try setting **displayconnects** parameter to false in manager.conf
See [this link](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html/asterisk-book.html#AMI_id265383)